# selected option not clearing from memory android

Tags: android, random, spinner

I have a small random number spinner that when you click gives a random number. I am having two problems. The first is when the main activity loads it displays a random number on the screen without the random number spinner being clicked. I am unsure what to set to false to keep it from opening with the main activity. The second problem is that when you select an option from the spinner it does not clear. Meaning that If you click on option D6 or D20 then you can not click on the same option again until selecting the other option first. Essentially  the selection does not clear out of memory after the random number is selected. Here is the random number code

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int roll = 0;
    boolean firstRun = false;
    // An item was selected.
    if (!firstRun)
    {
    if (spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()==0)
    {
        roll = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
    }
    else
    {
        roll = rand.nextInt(20)+1;
    }
    }
      else
       { firstRun = false;  }

    // Put the result into a string.
    String text = "You rolled a " + roll;
    // Build a dialog box and with the result string and a single button
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(text).setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new 
  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)  
  {
                    // do things when the user clicks ok.
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    // Show the dialog box.
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ...when the main activity loads it displays a random number on the screen without the random number spinner being clicked.

This is because `onItemSelected()` is called when the `Activity` is first created. To avoid running this code simply create a member variable (declared outside of a method, preferably before `onCreate()` for readability) like a `boolean`. And check that.  For example

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
    long id) 
{
    if (!firstRun)  // where firstRun is the boolean variable you create 
                    // and set to true
    {
        // run your code
    }
    else
   { firstRun = false;  }
}
```

> The second problem is that when you select an option from the spinner it does not clear.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this but you could set an empty value (`""`) for your first `position` then after each call to `onItemSelected()` call `setSelection(0)`

Comment: I can not use an empty value as I have the dice array say as an integer preloaded with 6 and 20. If I set a variable to true as you suggested would that prevent the code from running again when I want it to run?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `false`. I have edited.

Comment: I edited my code clip to add what you posted. Now when I run the app, it still displays a random number upon start up, and now it gives 0, 6,20 as clickable options, and all three options display a random number between 1 and 20.

Comment: This variable needs to be made a member variable, `boolean firstRun = false;` and it should be initialized as `true`. Define it outside of any method like before `onCreate()`

Comment: It still generates a random number when the app starts

Comment: Yes, you need to put the `Random` generator inside the first `if`. Everything should be inside the first `if` except for `firstRun = false`